# How to plot polar function onto cartesian grid?

Tags: java, math, graph, coordinate-systems

I have this polar function:

`r = A / log(B * tan(t / 2 * N)`

where A, B, N are arbitrary parameters and t is the angle theta in the polar coordinate system.

Example graph for `A=8, B=0.5, N=4`

[image: Sample graph]

How can I plot this function onto a Cartesian coordinate grid so I get an image like the one above?

thanks

Comment: -1. Seriously look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system and find out how to convert (r,t) into (x,y). If you have a programming question then post it again at SO.

Comment: @Raoul, your question contained no reference to any programming language whatsoever.  The fact is that your question is NPR, and only your answer and correct tagging makes it (barely) so.  Also, calling someone a jerk for being correct isn't acceptable behavior around here.

Comment: The programming language is irrelevant pseudocode is good enough but what I was asking for is how to draw a continuous curve like the image I posted, so essentially I wanted to know how to implement a function plotter that produced the image I've shown. I don't see how this is offtopic. Also I don't see how jalexiou is correct at all because he completely missed what the question was about obviously. Maybe may question wasn't clear enough but downvoting someone because of that is unacceptable behaviour from my POV and I call it what it is if you like it or not.

Comment: @Raoul it must be programming related to be on topic.  Its honestly as simple as that.  Pseudocode can be used to describe any algorithm, programming or otherwise.  If you're interested in the algorithm for creating such a graph, your question is off topic here.  If you want to know how to create such a graph in language XYZ, then it is on topic.  If you believe you're right, by all means go to [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) and continue your argument there.  I can tell you right now, however, that you'd be wasting your time.

Comment: So you are saying that algorithms are not related to programming?

Answer (score 2):

Incomplete pseudocode sample, but you should get the idea:

```
for t in [0, 2pi):
    r = /* whatever you got depending on t */
    x = r * cos(t)
    y = r * sin(t)
    draw line to (x,y)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm sorry to say this is not very helpful. This won't produce a smooth curve. How would you do that exactly with this pseudocode? Also please elaborate on how to iterate from 0 to 2pi because this is a continuous range of real numbers this isn't as easy as your pseudocode makes it out to be.

Comment: The answer exactly matches the question. Never in the original question metions that the answer has to produce a smooth curve (to what criteria?)

Comment: @ jalexiou I wrote "so I get an image like the one above"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. Some example Java code:

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class TestPolarPlot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int width = 512;
    final int height = 512;
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    final double A = 8;
    final double B = 0.5;
    final double N = 4;
    final double scale = 128;
    final double zoom = 50;
    final double step = 1 / scale;
    Point last = null;
    final Point origin = new Point(width/2, height/2);

    for (double t = 0; t <= 2*PI; t+= step) {
        final double r = zoom * polarFunction(t, A, B, N);
        final int x = (int)round(r * cos(t));
        final int y = (int)round(r * sin(t));
        Point next = new Point(x, y);
        if (last != null) {
            g.drawLine(origin.x + last.x, origin.y + last.y,
                origin.x + next.x, origin.y + next.y);
        }
        last = next;
    }

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("testit");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

    public static double polarFunction(double t, double A, double B, double N) {
        return A / log(B * tan(t / (2 * N)));
    }
}
```

I didn't expect this to create smooth curves but it works pretty well.

[image]
[image]

Comment: So by "i figured it out", you mean "i took the idea that i said was useless, tried it, and found out it actually works".